# How do I discover which application installed these programs

Tags: software-installation

How do I discover which application installed these programs?

`/usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store`, `tracker-extract`, `tracker-miner-fs`

It's eating up all my resources.  The CPU, one or two of them anyway,
 is well over 100% usage, The memory is very loaded, system load is over 50%,
 and disk read/write is very busy.

The man pages tell me it's a data miner set of programs for files on 
my system only.  `htop` tells me I am the owner.

Yesterday I installed some programs, all from the software center, with one
exception: Enthought Canopy, it's a Python IDE.

How do I discover which application installed these programs?